# Создание сложного триггера

Tags: mysql, триггер, mysql-workbench

мне нужно создать сложный триггер, точнее, необычный триггер. учитель хочет, чтобы мы её удивили. :) **можете пожалуйста написать несколько идеи насчёт сложных триггеров.**

**тема базы данных: мировые катастрофы.** тупая тема, знаю. в базе данных есть таблицы как 'место катастрофы', 'полная информация о катастрофе', 'вид катастрофы', 'поддерживающий фонд' и 'информация о пострадавших и время катастрофы'. была бы рада за помощь !

Comment: Пожалуйста. Создайте триггер, который позволяет при вставке в одну таблицу вставить записи в несколько связанных таблиц с соотв. разнесением данных.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.